# Where do I Store Time Zone and Language in Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, timezone

My program keeps user data in Active Directory. For each AD user I need to store his time zone and language. Are there standard AD attributes to store this information?

Answer (score 4):

You can simply add custom attributes to your AD.
Here is an example of tutorials.
[Custom AD attributes](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20319.how-to-create-a-custom-attribute-in-active-directory.aspx)